# Need help making my second HDD a system wide mount in Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: mount

Okay so long story short I set up my ubuntu 14.04 server as a time machine backup to back up my mac computers. I bought a 2tb WD RED drive to use for back ups. My macbook recognizes the time machine but I keep getting "osstatus error 2" when trying to connect to it and this has to do with permissions on the drive. Right now my WD red HDD location is /media/server (I named it server) and /media means its user specific I need it to be a system wide mount which is /mnt I believe. When I go into the disks program and click on the wheel the "edit mount options" is faded so I can't click on it. It also says "2.0tb unknown" where its suppose to show the partitions, I was wondering what I did wrong? My main drive which has ubuntu installed on it, and also a windows partition from my old computer I can change mount options fine its just this drive. I think I may have installed or formatted it wrong or something how can I fix this so I can system wide mount it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the output of `cat /etc/fstab; echo; mount; echo; ls -l /media/server`?

Comment: I posted the output in a comment below @AlaaAli

Answer (score 0):

First, create your mount point for the device like so:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/server
```

Note: you man use any name you choose for the mount point, i.e. `/mnt/foo` or `/mnt/bar` or whatever.

After this, create an fstab entry for your device.

`sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

The following link should help you out with that:
[Fstab - Community Help Wiki (Ubuntu)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

Note: it is advisable to use the UUID option for specifying the device, but using it's `/dev/sdX` location for the device is fine.

Next, ensure that your device is unmounted:

```
sudo umount /media/server
```

Now, attempt to automatically mount your 2TB hdd according to /etc/fstab specifications:

```
sudo mount /mnt/server
```

That should give you the mount point you are looking for and also configure it to automatically mount up at boot time.

Comment: I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu I have no idea how to create an fstab entry can you help me please?

Comment: Amended answer to incluse command to open `/etc/fstab` for editing. Use the provided linknto the Ubuntu wiki fstab page to learn gow to constuct the line. Note that you will only he adding one line into the file, notnimcluding comments.

Answer (score 0):

timemachine@brar-GA-MA78LM-S2H:~$ cat /etc/fstab; echo; mount; ls -1 /media/server

## /etc/fstab: static file system information.

#

## Entry for /dev/sda6 :

UUID=494aac22-8d5f-44eb-9483-04126a4d4b5e   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1

## Entry for /dev/sda2 :

UUID=949CA48C9CA46A86   /media/FACTORY_IMAGE    ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0   0

## Entry for /dev/sda1 :

UUID=B82ECEF22ECEA8A8   /media/HP   ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 00

## Entry for /dev/sda5 :

UUID=1B9C57F11BBEC3DB   /media/timemachine/server   ntfs-3g defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_US.UTF-8    0   0
UUID=47e3c635-9838-4c1c-bb00-7954752f87ff   none    swap    sw  0   0
/dev/fd0    /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8    0   0

/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda2 on /media/FACTORY_IMAGE type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda1 on /media/HP type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5 on /media/timemachine/server type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1002/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=timemachine)
gvfsd-fuse on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev)
ls: cannot access /media/server: No such file or directory

Comment: I have edited your question with this content. please add details into your question if asked by someone and don't post it as answer.Now you can delete this post. thanks